# ng-click inside label does not work

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

```html
<ion-view>
 <div class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
  <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
 </div>
 <ion-content class="has-header">
  <form ng-submit="doLogin()">
   <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input">
     <span class="input-label">手机号</span>
     <input type="text" ng-model="phonenumber" placeholder="这里输入手机号" maxlength="11">
     <button class="button button-dark" style="margin-right: 16px;" ng-click="getVerifyCode(111)">获取验证码</button>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
     <span class="input-label">验证码</span>
     <input type="password" ng-model="verifycode">
    </label>
    <label class="item">
     <button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="getVerifyCode(111)">登 陆</button>
    </label>
   </div>
  </form>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

1. why the button(获取验证码) inside label tag doesnt work?
2. but the button(登 陆) outside label tag work fine, why?
3. please help me to fixed this. I need to make a response when click
   the button(获取验证码)

Comment: simply use <div> instead. Found info related to this issue from official Ionic framework website: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/buttons-inside-form-labels/29033/2

Comment: thanks man, It work fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it works :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**working demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5t6acb?p=preview)

The solution is simply not to use a `label` for the item. Instead just use a `div`

**html**

```
<form ng-submit="doLogin()">
        <div class="list">
            <div class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">手机号</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="phonenumber" placeholder="这里输入手机号" maxlength="11">
                <!-- <input ></input> -->
                <button class="button button-dark" style="margin-right: 16px;" ng-click="getVerifyCode(111)">获取验证码</button>
            </div>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">验证码</span>
                <input type="password" ng-model="verifycode">
            </label>
            <label class="item">
                <button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="getVerifyCode(111)">登 陆</button>
            </label>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @ChenzhaoWudics:Glad to help you